# spring boot controller layer Using annotations to verify the length of the list of entries

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I want to use an annotation to limit the maximum length of the list to 10. I'm using the `@Max` annotation, but it doesn't work. Is there any way to do this?

```java
@Max(value = 10)
private List<String> ipRange;
```

Comment: Did you add @Valid before @RequestBody?

Comment: you can define it like this `List<String> list = Arrays.asList(new String[10])`

Answer (score 0):

You must use the [`@size`](https://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/api/org/hibernate/validator/Size.html) annotation as follow `@size(max = 10)`  because it is the right annotation to check size of lists as reported in the [javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/api/org/hibernate/validator/Size.html):

> Size range for Arrays, Collections or Maps

Instead the annotation [@max](https://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/api/org/hibernate/validator/Max.html) must be used to restrict range of numeric values, not sizes of item containers:

> max restriction on a numeric annotated element

Comment: Okay, I also used the size annotation at first, but then I looked at the Controller layer methods and found that they were not marked with the Validated annotation.
Now the problem is solved. Thanks.